# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Error while creating a window handler C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

So, hi.
I'm currently trying to make a 2D pokémon-style game. So i decided to make a Panel(so i only got the panel to move instead of everything) which would be ~50 000 PictureBoxes (tiles) of 30 by 30 pixels...

but it gives me this error..

[Error while creating a window handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfnAw.png)

So is there anyone who would be able to make the 50000 Pictureboxes to appear?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using World;

namespace World
{
    public partial class LoadWorld : Form
    {
        public int TileSizeX = 30;
        public int TileSizeY = 30;
        public int TileT = 50630;
        public int TileX = 225;
        public int TileY = 225;
        public PictureBox[] WorldTile = new PictureBox[50630];
        public static Dictionary<PictureBox, int[]> tileProp = new Dictionary<PictureBox, int[]>();
        public LoadWorld()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void LoadWorld_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int valueA = 0;
            int valueX = 0;
            int valueY = 0;
            foreach (PictureBox pictureBoxValue in WorldTile)
            {
                if(valueY < TileY)
                {
                    if(valueX < TileX)
                    {
                        WorldTile[valueA] = new PictureBox()
                        {
                            Size = new Size(TileSizeX, TileSizeY),
                            Location = new Point(valueX * 30, valueY * 30),
                            BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("Sprites/null.png"),
                            Visible = true,
                            Name = "tile" + valueA
                        };
                        WorldMap.Controls.Add(WorldTile[valueA]);
                        valueA = valueA + 1;
                        valueX = valueX + 1;
                    }
                    else if(valueX == TileX)
                    {
                        WorldTile[valueA] = new PictureBox()
                        {
                            Size = new Size(TileSizeX, TileSizeY),
                            Location = new Point(valueX * 30, valueY * 30),
                            BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("Sprites/null.png"),
                            Visible = true,
                            Name = "tile" + valueA,
                         };
                        WorldMap.Controls.Add(WorldTile[valueA]);
                        valueA = valueA + 1;
                        valueY = valueY + 1;
                        valueX = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if(valueY == TileY)
                {
                    if (valueX < TileX)
                    {
                        WorldTile[valueA] = new PictureBox()
                        {
                            Size = new Size(TileSizeX, TileSizeY),
                            Location = new Point(valueX * 30, valueY * 30),
                            BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("Sprites/null.png"),
                            Visible = true,
                            Name = "tile" + valueA,
                        };
                        WorldMap.Controls.Add(WorldTile[valueA]);
                        valueX = valueX + 1;
                        valueA = valueA + 1;
                    }
                    else if (valueX == TileX)
                    {
                        WorldTile[valueA] = new PictureBox()
                        {
                            Size = new Size(TileSizeX, TileSizeY),
                            Location = new Point(valueX * 30, valueY * 30),
                            BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("Sprites/null.png"),
                            Visible = true,
                            Name = "tile" + valueA,

                        };
                        WorldMap.Controls.Add(WorldTile[valueA]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is that `Windows.Forms` is not really well suited for this task.

Each of the `PictureBox` controls creates a system `Handle`. The `System.Windows.Forms.Control` actually wraps a `HWND`. This gives `Windows.Forms` controls some operating system features such as painting, mouse hit testing, out of the box.

The problem is that the system has limits - you can have at most **10,000 handles per process and 66,536 handles per user session**. Here you can see right away that creating 50,000 `PictureBox` controls is way **beyond the limits** of what `Windows.Forms` can achieve.

Even if you were able to do this, the whole rendering process would be extremely slow and the game would be absolutely unplayable.

I would suggest to ditch `Windows.Forms` and look for an alternative. First option is to use `WPF`, which would handle a big number of controls without a problem. But it still is not the best choice for a game.

You could choose [Monogame](http://www.monogame.net/) to implement this however. You can use Monogame in UWP or in WPF. It is a very easy to learn game framework in C# which could suit your needs very well.

If you want even more control, you can look into `Unity`, which is a complete game development solution. Your game could then be ported to many different platforms including UWP, Android and iOS.